# How would I fix this if statement in C to get it working as intended?

Tags: c, if-statement

In this piece of code for a "contact management system" I am having difficulty in getting the intended output for a line. Basically, during this one part when you are adding a new contact, it asks you to "please enter an apartment #" as shown below:

```
 if (yes() == 1)
 {
     printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
     address->apartmentNumber = getInt();
     if (address->apartmentNumber > 0)
     {
     }
     else
     {
        printf("*** INVALID INTEGER *** <Please enter an integer>: ");
        address->apartmentNumber = getInt();
    }
  }
  else
  {
      address->apartmentNumber = 0;
  }
```

Now, according to my assignment, you're supposed to enter the word (instead of a number, get it?) "bison" which brings up the output:

> *** INVALID INTEGER *** Please enter an integer:

For context, this part works absolutely fine. However, you're then directed to put in the integer "-1200" which should then bring up the prompt

> *** INVALID APARTMENT NUMBER *** Please enter a positive number:

It is this part that I'm having issue in because simply put, I don't know where to put it, whether in the if statement or outside of it. Im not sure, and would kindly like some help with this.

I have attempted to correct the problem my self, but it just gives me double of the Invalid integer output instead of this correct Invalid apartment number statement. Here is my (failed) attempt:

```
    if (yes() == 1)
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
        address->apartmentNumber = getInt();

        if (address->apartmentNumber > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            printf("*** INVALID INTEGER *** <Please enter an integer>: ");
            address->apartmentNumber = getInt();
        }
        if (address->apartmentNumber < 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            printf("*** INVALID APARTMENT NUMBER *** <Please enter a positive number>: ");
            address->apartmentNumber = getInt();       
        }
        else
        {
            address->apartmentNumber = 0;
        }
```

EDIT: For those who've asked for the code for getInt() and yes(), Here:

getInt()

```
int getInt(void)
{
    int num;
    char nl;

    scanf("%d%c", &num, &nl);
    while (nl != '\n') {
        clearKeyboard();

        printf("*** INVALID INTEGER *** <Please enter an integer>: ");
        scanf("%d%c", &num, &nl);
    }
    return num;
}
```

and yes():

```
int yes(void)
{
    int yesno, flag;
    char c, nl;
    scanf("%c%c", &c, &nl);

    do {
        if (nl != '\n') {
            clearKeyboard();

            printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
            flag = 1;
            scanf("%c%c", &c, &nl);
        }
        else if (c != 'Y' && c != 'y' && c != 'N' && c != 'n') {
            printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
            flag = 1;
            scanf("%c%c", &c, &nl);
        }
        else if (nl == '\n' && (c == 'Y' || c == 'y' || c == 'N' || c == 'n')) 
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    } while (flag == 1);

    if (c == 'Y' || c == 'y') {
        yesno = 1;
    }
    else {
        yesno = 0;
    }
    return yesno;
}
```

Comment: Huh? You need to tighten this up a bit. And what does `yes()` and `getInt()` do?

Comment: Those are functions. this is an absolutely massive assignment with alot of code on multiple c and header files. you could pretend that they're not there and improvise as if they weren't needed if that helps at all

Comment: Any suitable fix must propagate into getInt(). Hint: number 0.

Comment: Can you share the code for `getInt`, and preferably for `yes` as well?

Comment: @Joshua Huh? I'm confused by this statement. I'd like an example of what you mean

Comment: @selbie sure, not an issue, however just know that they are located in a seperate c file. going to edit the post shortly!

Comment: @Aaron - He's suggesting that maybe  `getInt` returns 0 to indicate that non-numeric input was given.  But we won't know until you post the code for `getInt`

Comment: why don't use `bool` for `yes()`?

Comment: @phuclv what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean exactly that. Instead of returning `int`, just return a `_Bool` (or `bool` in stdbool.h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getInt` will take care of non-integer (text and words) input and will reprompt the user to type an integer until he does.

So your code needs to be more like this:

```
if (yes() == 1)
{
     int validNumber = 0;
     while (validNumber == 0)
     {
         printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
         address->apartmentNumber = getInt();
         if (address->apartmentNumber > 0)
         {
             validNumber = 1;
         }
         else
         {
             printf("* INVALID APARTMENT NUMBER * Please enter a positive number:\n");
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: this may work, but it tells me that valid input is undefined. where am i supposed to define it? "bool" "false" and "true" say that they're undefined which causes an error when building the solution

Comment: It's literally defined for you as `bool validInput = false;`  What more do you need?

Comment: I mean that it underlines bool, false and true in red in visual studio. Whenever i go hover over any of those 3, it says they are undefined and give me errors to which i cannot build the solution, and then move on to debugging. thats what I mean...

Comment: I'm inclined to believe you aren't past the "hello world" stage of learning C yet.  Have you familiarized yourself with basic programming concept such as loops, booleans, conditional logic, etc...   I've changed `validNumber` to be an integer just in case your C compiler doesn't recognize the bool syntax in C yet. If that doesn't work, you're on your own to learn the basics of program structure and variable declarations.

Comment: @Aaron - yes, do that.

Comment: Edit: I fixed the issue myself. Turns out i just needed to put address->apartmentNumber = getInt(); in the else statement, i have clicked the checkmark on your comment selbie. cheers!

Comment: @selbie the native bool type in C is `_Bool`. You have to include `stdbool.h` to get the `bool` macro, unlike C++ where `bool` is a built-in type

Answer (score 0):

Your `getint()` function is horribly fragile. What is to say the user enters a non-integer value only once? When taking input of a specific type, it is generally better to loop continually until you receive valid input (or the user cancels input), and always protect against the of the input not being what you expect (like when a cat steps on the keyboard...)

`scanf` can be used, if used correctly. This means **you** are responsible for checking the **return** of `scanf` *every time*. You must handle *three conditions*

1. `(return == EOF)` the user canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or on windows <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>, but see [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10 (early versions)](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/));
2. `(return < expected No. of conversions)` a *matching* or *input* failure occurred. For a *matching* failure you must account for every character left in your input buffer. (scan forward in the input buffer reading and discarding characters until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is found); and finally
3. `(return == expected No. of conversions)` indicating a successful read -- it is then up to you to check whether the input meets any additional criteria (e.g. positive integer, positive floating-point, within a needed range, etc..).

Putting that to work with your `getint()` function and passing a character string to be displayed as a user prompt (if not `NULL`), you could do something similar to:

```
int getint (int *value, const char *prompt)
{
    /* loop continually until good input or canceled */
    for (;;) {
        int rtn;        /* variable for return from scanf */
        if (prompt)                     /* if not NULL    */
            fputs (prompt, stdout);     /* display prompt */
        rtn = scanf ("%d", value);      /* attempt read   */

        if (rtn == EOF) {   /* check for manual EOF */
            fputs ("<user canceled input>\n", stderr);
            return 0;
        }
        empty_stdin();  /* all other cases - empty input buffer */
        if (rtn == 1)   /* good input, break */
            break;
        /* otherwise matching failure */
        fputs ("  error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
    }
    return *value;  /* value also available through pointer */
}
```

(**note:** the value returned from the function is the validation for whether the function succeeded (a return of `1`) or whether the user canceled with `EOF` (a return of `0`), the integer value is made available to the caller through the pointer `value`)

The helper function `empty_stdin()` is simply:

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

There are many ways to put `getint()` together to tailor it to your needs, as long as you proper handle all three cases above, you are free to do it any way you like.